# How to analyse the results of a netstat command on Windows, as during the night my internet connection slows down?

Tags: tcp, netstat

My internet connection gets very slow at night and my ISP told me to use netstat to see how many tcp connetions there is there is usually about 30 or more with ether time wait established but I also did this during the day time and it still have about 20 tcp connetions but my internet speed was not afected they also said I must have a virus.

I have used cc cleaner,spybot avast,panda,bitdefender,fsecure,este virus scans and found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using wi-fi? Do you have many neighbours? If so, it could be interference on the wi-fi frequencies that occurs when everyone is home, but not during the day.

Try connecting to your router with an ethernet cable only.

Comment: yes using wi-fi one neighbour next door then the next neighbour is about 30 meaters away on my ipod  when it serches for wi fi it only finds one more connetion

Comment: Microwave ovens, home wireless phones and a bunch of other thing can interfere with wi-fi. I suggest trying a ethernet cable when wi-fi is bad. That way you can determine if it is the wi-fi or not